# Is it possible to set the .env values file dynamically from database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, environment-variables

I am writing a new Laravel application and I and want to set env values i.e. database details, mailer details, general configuration while installing the project from a blade view.
Is it possible to store these variables in the database and then pass them to the .env file?

Answer (score 1):

The .env file is meant to be static and contain the static data (like DB user & pass) to load dynamic configurations.

If you want dynamic configs, you can just load them on app startup via a service provider.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the values of environment variables using config function.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

`config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);`

Similarly, you can do it for other configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the contents of the .env file, you'll have to use some kind of string replace in combination with PHP's file writing methods. For some inspiration, you should take a look at the key:generate command: KeyGenerateCommand.php:

```
$path = base_path('.env');

if (file_exists($path)) {
    file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
        'APP_KEY='.$this->laravel['config']['app.key'], 'APP_KEY='.$key, file_get_contents($path)
    ));
}
```

After the file path is built and the existence is checked, the command simply replaces APP_KEY=[current app key] with APP_KEY=[new app key]. You should be able to do the same string replacement with other variables.
Last but not least I just wanted to say that it might isn't the best idea to let users change the .env file. For most custom settings I would recommend storing them in the database, however this is obviously a problem if the setting itself is necessary to connect to the database.

Comment: Actually I am looking for an installer .. just like we get one with wordpress where it takes the database info and create a superadmin user at the beginning. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes you can do it. In index.php/file which execute first,  write such a script which take input from user once it submit create .env file dynamically. Hope this  will make sense